# Digital elevation model - getting files in the .DEM extension

Tags: dem, terrain

Could you tell me from where can I get the Digital Elevation Model data in the .DEM file extension?
The option for QGIS here:
https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/working_with_terrain.html
shows the USGS way, but there is an option for GeoTIFF only.
For my purpose (terrain analysis in the [Kasmir 3D software](https://www.kashmir3d.com/kash/manual-e/map_usgs.htm) I need it in the .DEM version.

All links provided there are inactive, which is out of wonders since the data comes from 2004 year.

Could anyone share some hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geospatial Data Abstraction Library (GDAL) will allow you to convert many open raster file types to a USGS DEM.   The QGIS GDAL processing toolbox has a tool called Translate (convert formats).  Translate (convert formats) allows you to choose USGS DEM as the output.

Comment: There is no "COnvert format" in the SAGA. It appears in the GDAL, however the output file is still tif.
I found something here:
https://freegeographytools.com/2010/converting-dem-files-to-asc-format-for-terrain-bender-creating-matching-raster-overlays
https://sagatutorials.wordpress.com/import-and-view-digital-elevation-data/
and I will try these solutions. 
Anyhow if you know how to find it easily, I appreciate in advance :)

Comment: OK, there is a multitute of options, while .dem and .asc

Comment: @Mariusz Krujar - Your right, Translate is not in the SAGA processing window it is in GDAL.  My bad.  I have edited may answer.  I just tried converting an ESRI GRID to DEM, and a single band TIF, and both worked just fine in outputting to DEM.  Can you make your data available?  If so, I can give it a try.

Comment: Basically I downloaded the DEM from USGS in the Tiff version. Unfortunately, the QGIS probably doesn't transform it correctly as I am getting the file corrupted in the Kashmir 3D software.